# Magento 2 : set product image programatically

Tags: magento2, product, product-images

I want to upload a product along with product image, please suggest how to set path or upload image for a product.
here is my code

```
 try{
                $_product->setName($product["name"]);
                $_product->setTypeId('simple');
                $_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
                $_product->setSku($product["sku"]);
                $_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
                $_product->setVisibility(4);
                $_product->setDescription($product["description"]);
                $_product->setPrice($product["price"]);

                $tmpDir = $this->getMediaDirTmpDir();
                $this->file->checkAndCreateFolder($tmpDir);
                $newFileName = $tmpDir . baseName($imageUrl);
                $result = $this->file->read($imageUrl, $newFileName);
                 if ($result) {
                /** add saved file to the $product gallery */
                $_product->setMediaGallery(array('images'=>array (),'values'=>array ())); 
                $_product->addImageToMediaGallery(how to set path, what to do,array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, $visible);
                }

         'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
   'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                        'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                        'is_in_stock' => $product['stockstatus'], //Stock Availability
                        'qty' =>  $product['quantity']
                        )
                    );
                $_product->save();

            }                             
            catch(\Exception $e) { 
                 echo $e->getMessage();
            }
```

Comment: i am suggesting you please try this in test script from root folder and hard code the image path first, if it works then do it dynamically next https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259303/add-remove-image-programmatically-to-product-magento2

Comment: i did but always got `image does not exist` this error

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this code after product price (No need another code for upload image)

```
 $imagePath = "D:\image\sample.jpg"; // path of the image
 $_product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, false);
 $_product->save();
```

Comment: is the same path of all the words system ?

Comment: no luck @israt :(

Answer (score 0):

```
 use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
 require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

 $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

 $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

 $state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
 $state->setAreaCode('frontend');

 try
 {
  
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $importDir = __DIR__ . '/pub/media/catalog/product'; //This is the directory path from where you have to take the images
  
  $i = '12'; // It must be product ID for which product it is to be assigned
  
  $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($i);
   
  $id = $product->getId();
  $url = $importDir . $product->getImage();
  $product->addImageToMediaGallery($url, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, false);
  $product->save();
  echo "<br /><br /> $id Product Save Succefully";
 
 }
 catch(\Exception $e)
 {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  exit;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($productImages as $key => $productImage) {
    if ($key === array_key_first($productImages)) {
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($productImage, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, false);
        continue;
    }
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($productImage, [], true, false);
}
$product->save();
```